# Permissions setup for nodejs

Tags: permissions, node.js

I have several application running on my server; they are built in meteor.js so they are nodejs process and I run them using forever npm module;

I currently launch forever for all of them using the same user whose group owns all the websites directories;
now that this is gonna become a production server, I'd like to understand better about security issues this can cause; are there some general security rules to follow to launch nodejs process? Is my current approach possibly dangerous?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that your application doesn't need write access to the application data (which it really shouldn't), we do the following:

We break the users into two classes - `node-<app>-runtime` and `node-<app>-data`. `<app>` being the application name. They are both part of a group `node-<app>`. Those aren't the actual names we use for the nosy ones out there.

We do the following:

1) For building the application, we always build on a separate machine, and then have a npm `dist` script which places only the files *needed* to run the application into a `/dist` directory and ships a tarred copy of this directory to our deploy server. The advantage of this is twofold - we know exactly what's going into the deploy and we can make sure that any dev-deps in `node_modules`, `.git` directories, and other data doesn't get added to production machines. It also means that when GitHub/Npm/etc. goes down, it doesn't break autoscaling etc. - our deploy server just delivers the prebuilt tarball.

2) We use our configuration management system to create a log directory in a standardized location which can be written to by `node-<app>-runtime` with permissions 640. The path is provided to the application by a standard Environment Variable. Our log processing daemon automatically picks these up and ships them to a remote server.

3) Our deploy system places the application files in a specific place and sets them to be owned by `node-<app>-data` with permissions 640. The path is provided to the application by a standard Environment Variable.

The only other bit of advice I have is to always make sure you are setting `NODE_ENV=production`. Many node modules use this convention to turn off debugging symbols, or improve performance (`express` comes to mind).

Comment: I would also use PM2 over forever for production management (actually, I would really use the inbuilt system manager and cluster.js) as it will let your application fully use a multi-core machine and do rolling HUP's.